# Why there are two database.php in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am new in laravel and I found two file with name database.php

First:

> app/config/local/database.php

Second:

> app/config/database.php

What is the different between usage of these files?

Comment: One is used as a supplement/override to the `default` if the `environment` value is set as "local" (typically for development), the other is the `default` configuration. See the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: Keep in mind that Laravel 5 uses environment variables rather than the individual files now (project/.env).

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel 4** uses `config/ENVIRONMENT/*` to allow developers to specify configurations for a given environment. If a configuration file isn't found in the `config/ENVIRONMENT` directory it will use the default configuration in `config/`.

**Laravel 5** uses a `.env` configuration file to easily add environment variables. You simply tell your configuration file `config/database.php` to retrieve these variables dynamically.